# {JMeter} How do I test same websites with different GUID?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to test a few of the websites on JMeter where they belong to the same websites but with different GUID.

Examples of the mentioned website would be:

```
www.example.com/api/example/example/{guid}
```

{guid} - A series of randomly generated strings in UNIX timestamp format.

Answer (score 0):

There is [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)  which returns current time in form of a [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) so all you need to do is to replace `{guid}` with `${__time(,)}`

Demo:

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.